# Mvc pagedlist - PagedListPager with Id attribute from Viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am trying to use `Pagedlist` pagination in `Mvc 5`. Pagination is working fine, however the list is containing transactions only with a specific id. The id is passed on with `Viewbag` and the first list shows up, but when I am trying to view the second page of the list, it will not work because it requires the id number which is can not be null. I added the id to the `Url.Action` but still does not pass on anything. Also tried to view the id number in the view, just to see if it works and nothing comes up. Any solution?

Link in the first view that passes the id number and directs to the list.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Statement", "CheckingAccount", new { checkingAccountId = ViewBag.CheckingAccountId })" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print Statement
</a>
```

Pagination shows up, but can not access the second or any other bits of the list. I used the following the pass further on the same id number but nothing.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Statement", new { page, PageSize = Model.PageSize, checkingAccountId = ViewBag.CheckingAccountId } ))
```

If I manually type the id into the browser such as

```
statement?page=1&pageSize=4&CheckingAccountId=1
```

it works, but I need this to be passed on via the `PagedListPager`

This is in my controller

```
public ActionResult Statement(int checkingAccountId, int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
{
    var checkingAccount = db.CheckingAccounts.Find(checkingAccountId);
    List<Transaction> statement = checkingAccount.Transactions.ToList();
    ViewBag.CheckingAccountId = checkingAccountId;
    PagedList<Transaction> model = new PagedList<Transaction>(statement, page, pageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```

When I fire it up, it will take me to `/statement?checkingAccountId=1` which works and shows the first 4 statements, but when I am trying to see the rest of the statement, `PagedListPager` will only have `statement?Page=1&pageSize=4`  which will come up with an error for missing the checkingAccountId

Comment: Are you setting the value of `ViewBag.CheckingAccountId` in the `Statement()` method when you return the view? You need to show the controller code

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Statement", new { checkingAccountId = ViewContext.ViewBag.CheckingAccountId, page, PageSize = Model.PageSize } ))
```

`ViewContext` needed to be added in order to get the `checkingAccountId` from the viewbag... and also declared the id again in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Statement(int checkingAccountId, int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
{
    var checkingAccount = db.CheckingAccounts.Find(checkingAccountId);
    List<Transaction> statement = checkingAccount.Transactions.ToList();
    ViewBag.CheckingAccountId = checkingAccountId;
    PagedList<Transaction> model = new PagedList<Transaction>(statement, page, pageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```